# IE10 on Windows 7 Side-by-Side IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

Can I install [IE10 Preview for Windows 7](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Info/Downloads/Default.html) and keep the previous IE8 version for development testing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't believe you will be able to run IE8 and IE10 side-by-side on the same machine. Instead, I would encourage you to use the [browser-emulation options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx) found within the F12 Developer Tools. From there you can instruct IE10 to behave as though it were IE8.

If emulation isn't desirable, and you're not interested in downloading a [virtual machine image](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575), you could also consider exploring the [BrowserStack service](http://www.browserstack.com/start). It will allow you to spin up IE8 on multiple versions of Windows, and view both remote and local files.

Comment: Great resources - I've known about the emulation capabilities via **F12** and also **VM images** - but I've not seen the VMs on-demand that support native interaction with different platforms and browsers. I can see real use for **browserstack**.

Comment: The question I have is, how close does emulated IE8 match the actual functionality of native IE8? Are there known differences or bugs in one that aren't in the other?

Comment: @JDSmith There are indeed some differences that I've ran into, though I have not cataloged them.

Comment: fair warning, F12 Emulator options don't properly emulate the browser versions.

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus They don't *fully* emulate other browser versions. Meaning, there isn't a perfect representation of IE8 within IE11. That being said, there are a lot of things IE11 *properly* emulates about IE8.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a more reliable option for developers

[IE 1-8 Standalones](http://finalbuilds.com/iecollection.htm)

it contains

- Internet Explorer 1.0 (4.40.308)
- Internet Explorer 1.5 (0.1.0.10)
- Internet Explorer 2.01 (2.01.046)
- Internet Explorer 3.0 (3.0.1152)
- Internet Explorer 3.01 (3.01.2723)
- Internet Explorer 3.03 (3.03.2925)
- Internet Explorer 4.01 (4.72.3110.0)
- Internet Explorer 5.01 (5.00.3314.2100)
- Internet Explorer 5.5 (5.51.4807.2300)
- Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2800.1106)
- Internet Explorer 6.0 (6.00.2900.2180)
- Internet Explorer 7.0 (7.00.5730.13)
- Internet Explorer 8.0 (8.00.6001.18702)

Comment: Once you've upgraded to IE10 it doesn't let you install IE7/IE8, IE6 is as high as you can go.

Answer (score 5):

Also consider IETester - http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

You can run tabs side by side in different browser versions. Works well for my web dev testing.

[image: IETester]

Answer (score 5):

MS started an extra Homepage for IE testing. Lots of options under http://loc.modern.ie/

[image]

Comment: this is the best answer imo. VM's available for proper testing of all browsers.

Comment: But they're clunky and slow as hell. It's far from optimal.

Comment: Depends on your Hardware and VM. Quite fast here with VM-Ware Workstation and 16GB Ram.

Comment: Link broken; It redirects to the developer homepage. Did this move?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider VMware thinApp (virtualize Application) or Microsoft RemoteApp (Run application from remote server).

In my environment, I have amix of thinApp and RemoteApp (some application virtualized (ThinApp) and then accessed using RemoteApp).