# Way to make IE 10 open in IE8 mode

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10, ie8-browser-mode

does anyone know how can i force IE 10 to open in IE8 browser mode. Is it possible, Change something in IE settings? Does IE have some kind of a config file what can define it? Or can i make some changes in REGEDIT to force it to open in IE8 mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you want **cross-browser testing**, take a look [here](http://www.browserstack.com/). This offers multiple browser testing without the need to have virtual machines etc.

If your specifically looking for IE, then take a look [here](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE).

**EDIT**: You can look at [IE10 on Windows 7 Side-by-Side IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382149/ie10-on-windows-7-side-by-side-ie8) for the issue you have.

Comment: Im specifically looking for IE, and IE 8 . But im using win 7 and IE 8 are not supported. So, i need to use IE 10 and force it to be in IE8 browser mode. 
(This actually is for UI testing, where i need IE to always start in IE 8 browser mode)